# Custom Page Template VS Plugin VS Shortcode refer to function

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to create a form that will be called many times through application .
below is the steps i did :

1- Create a form.php page and place it in my child theme folder.

> C:\wamp\www\test\wp-content\themes\designfolio-child

i wrote the below code at the top of the page

```
<?php /* Template Name: Hercal Template */ ?>
```

and then i write my form code.

2-This page calls another PHP files and Jquery file , i place those file in

> C:\wamp\www\test

3- I create a wordpress page and select a template option 'Hercal Template' , 
The page run now ,form loaded and working fine but i have some issue that i need to understand.

---

1-What about security , is it secure to place files and database connection to test folder directly ?
2-How can i call my form inside other pages ?
3-the above steps enables me to create a template page , so what is the difference between template page , plugin , short code that refer a function ???

I mean :

1. when i create a plugin , i can call it anywhere by using function name.
2. when i create a function,place it into wp-content and create shortcode for it , i can call it anywhere by using shortcode .

so what is the difference between them , i have conflict between (page template,plugin,shortcode).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use shortcode to display form.

if you will use template than you can't put extra content/design for multiple places.

if you will use function than you have to call that in your page or you need to physically edit template file.

if you will use your form as shortcode than you can access/call it anywhere in your page/post/custom post and place it on anywhere between the div, paragraph etc.

Even you can access it on php file as well

I suggest you to use short code

Comment: Good but what about plugins ?

Comment: For plugin, it's up to you. if you don't want to put your code in functions.php than make it as plugin.

Comment: so thats the only difference between Plugin and Function ?

Comment: you can have the function in your plugin and it would accessible